# C++ Visibility macro breaking documentation Sphinx/Doxygen formatting

Tags: c++, python-sphinx, doxygen

I have this problem where I added a macro to set the visibility of certain functions to my code like this:

```cpp
#define PUBLIC_API __attribute__((visibility("default")))
```

The problem is that it seems to have broken the formatting when displaying the functions in Sphinx..

Changing the function docs from this:

```cpp
struct conductor* conductor_create(struct conductor_error* err);
```

[image]

to this:

```cpp
PUBLIC_API struct conductor* conductor_create(struct conductor_error* err);
```

[image]

Is there any way I can get that nice auto-formatting back? I would like to not see the macro there at all if possible..

Here's what I was using in the Sphinx .rst for that part if that's relevant:

````
C API
=====
```/lib/c++/X2XConductorC.h```

.. doxygenfile:: X2XConductorC.h
   :project: X2XConductor
````

I set up the documentation more or less as described here:
https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/clear-functional-c-documentation-with-sphinx-breathe-doxygen-cmake/

Comment: I've just figured out you can get doxygen to ignore blocks of code with the tags:
```
///@cond INTERNAL
PUBLIC_API
///@endcond
```
I've done this in the function declarations and it's good enough for my purposes, but if there's a proper way of going about it please do share

Comment: Please also have a look at `\internal` and at the doxygen PREDEFINED configuration setting (for PUBLIC_API)

Comment: I managed to resolve this problem by enabling `MACRO_EXPANSION` in the Doxyfile configuration. This might not work if you still want to have the macro in the documentation (or if it always has a definition), but it seemed to work for my visibility macros

Comment: I ended up moving documenting the functions in the source `.c` file instead of the header file. Former doesn't contain the visibility macros so everything works fine.